# Spring WSS "wsse:security" tag

Tags: soap, spring-ws, signing

I am signing a SOAP message on using Spring, this [doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html#d4e2758) to be exactly. There is no difference between my configuration and the one described in the documentation. Everything is working and I am signing the outgoing message and the header looks like

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Signature-1">
        ...
        </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

However, the problem is that the server is expecting something like

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Signature-1">
    ...
    </ds:Signature>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

So, the server doesn't like my petition. I cannot change anything on the server so I need to find a solution. If a use soapUI to generate a Request, in the request there is no `wsse:Security` tag so what server is expecting is aligned with its WSDL.

I have googled few hours with no luck. Is there anyway to remove `wsse:Security` tag? Can I resolve this with Spring or I should implement some custom code?

Comment: I have found that that tag has nothing to do with Spring because Spring delegates this task to `org.apache.ws.security` package. Thinkng that maybe problem is totally on server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not sure if this is the best answer but this is what I have found out.

Spring WS security focuses on the three different areas of WS-Security: Authentication, Digital signatures and Encryption/Decryption according with [WS-Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security).

Two of these three areas, Authentication and Digital signatures, are covered by [XML Signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Signature) so if you just want to sign and/or authenticate your message without encryption/decryption you can use XML Signature directly and not as part of WS-Security. That was my case, client just expecting `<ds:Signature... >` directly and not under `<wsse:Security ...>`

I did not find how to do this (the whole thing) with Spring WS, so I implemented it using [XMLSignature](http://santuario.apache.org/Java/api/org/apache/xml/security/signature/XMLSignature.html) from Apache WSS4J package that is the the same that Spring does to sign the message.